# Update a column by comparing two different columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `TEST` with columns `VALUE,VALUE_SIM,SIM_STATUS,ID`. I want to update the column `SIM_STATUS` for the `ID = 288`. I also want to display the columns after updating.

The conditions are :

```
1. SIM_STATUS = 0 when VALUE = VALUE_SIM.
2. SIM_STATUS = 1 when VALUE < VALUE_SIM.
3. SIM_STATUS = 2 when VALUE > VALUE_SIM.
```

I wrote the following query but it is showing an error.

```
("UPDATE TEST"
 "SET SIM_STATE = ( CASE WHEN VALUE = VALUE_SIM THEN SIM_STATE = 0 END )"
 "SET SIM_STATE = ( CASE WHEN VALUE < VALUE_SIM THEN SIM_STATE = 1 END )"
 "SET SIM_STATE = ( CASE WHEN VALUE > VALUE_SIM THEN SIM_STATE = 2 END )"
 "where ID = 288 ");
```

Comment: ERROR : QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '='. [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Anweisung(en) konnte(n) nicht vorbereitet werden."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query that you want is:

```
UPDATE TEST
    SET SIM_STATE = (CASE WHEN VALUE = VALUE_SIM THEN 0
                          WHEN VALUE < VALUE_SIM THEN 1
                          WHEN VALUE > VALUE_SIM = 2
                     END)
WHERE NUMBER = 288;
```

Your query has several syntax errors.  I don't even know if you intend for the double quotes to be part of the query.

Comment: I also want to display the colums after updating.

Comment: If you have another question, then it is appropriate to ask as a question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This would do i guess

```
UPDATE TEST
SET 
  SIM_STATE = 
   CASE   WHEN VALUE  < VALUE_SIM THEN  1
+  CASE   WHEN VALUE > VALUE_SIM THEN 2
+  CASE   WHEN VALUE  = VALUE_SIM THEN 0

WHERE ID = 1
```